# Windows 8 version specifically for Mac

Tags: macos, mac, bootcamp, parallels-desktop, windows

I really dont understand this. My school sells products to students via [onthehub.com.](http://onthehub.com)

They offer a separate version of Windows 8 Pro that they claim is specifically for Macs. How does this make any sense? They say it is tailored to work with parallels or bootcamp and those type of things.

I am assuming they are only making the claim for 'security' sake? Let me know your two cents. I really just want to use it on my PC.

Comment: can you link directly to the product you're talking about?  AFAIK Microsoft does not offer this, it may be some sort of marketing bundle offered by the reseller.

Comment: Specifically this is what it says "Microsoft Windows 8 Professional Upgrade 32/64-bit Mac Version (English) (Student Option) - Download"

Also no direct link because it is university specific.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps they have selected an OEM version or otherwise made sure that the version being selected somehow addresses the need they perceive their Mac community would prefer.

The upgrade pricing seems odd since OS X isn't an eligible version for consumer upgrades, but perhaps the university has negotiated a special agreement and wants to only offer the upgrade price to Mac users and not PC users?

Answer (score 0):

I have used onthehub.com to purchase a Windows 8 license recently.  I saw the distinction between the regular and Mac versions while I was browsing the site.  I was actually going to buy one of each, a regular version of Windows 8 Pro for my PC and a Mac version for my Parallels VM on my Mac.  The site wouldn't let me buy both.  It appears that there is a licensing restriction that OnTheHub will only let you buy one or the other.

Maybe that ties into the reason for having a separate Mac version - you are then blocked from buying the traditional PC install.